# Editing and saving CSV file to use in plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, csv, excel, time-series

For using in a plugin (PS Time Series Viewer), I want to edit a CSV file in the way plugin wants. Somehow I think there's a problem with the CSV file. I would like to tell you all my steps because I cannot diagnose the problem properly.

I edited with MS Excel and saved the CSV file. I called it into QGIS (Layer/Add Layer/Add delimited text layer). I saved as shapefile (export/save feature as) this point layer. At this step, when I clicking a point with PS Time Series tool, I get an error. The error message is "No time series values found for the selected point".

I attached my CSV file and the plugin's test data (It is given as shapefile, and when I try on this, the plugin works very well).

Original CSV file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5z529wwzzmu6cy/_MyOriginalCSV.csv?dl=0

Edited CSV file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i67bex4kzxehmqw/_MyEditedCSV.csv?dl=0

Plugin's test data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs35nhwze77y86n/_PluginsTestShapeFile.rar?dl=0

Error message: https://www.dropbox.com/s/24c244qdl6565bj/Photo%2030.03.2019%2020%2007%2048.jpg?dl=0

Is there any problem with my CSV file or I missed another point?

QGIS version: 3.6
PS Time Series version: 0.3.1

Comment: What is the error that you get?  Can you. edit your question to show the error?

Comment: @Stu Smith Hello, I edited the post. I get this error for all points: ‘No time series values found formthe selected point.’

Comment: do you have some sample CSV file that works with the plugin?

Comment: @aborruso No. But I have a working shapefile. You can download (plugin’s test data) in the post. In addition, I export the shape file as a csv and then save as a shapefile. And It did not worked too.