# Changing coordinates of points in the Attribute Table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, coordinates

I have a shapefile. Within the shapefile, there are approximately 500 points.

[image]

I want to change the coordinates of these points in the Attribute Table. But there is no coordinate column in Attribute Table.

[image]

Is there an easy way to change the coordinates?

Comment: From what to what do you want to change the coordinates? Should the change in the attribute table also move the point to said coordinate?

Comment: I change the coordinates in the attribute table and points will move to said coordinates.

Comment: That is to my knowledge not possible and never has been. In QGIS 2.18 you could use the `node tool` to mark points and change their coordinates manually. But since you have points, you simply may export the data as CSV, change the coordinates and reload the data.

Comment: I have many points. Very hard to move manually. In fact, because of I couldn't solve CSV problem in my previous question, I ask this question. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317225/editing-and-saving-csv-file-to-use-in-plugin-for-qgis

Comment: Yeah, but if you don't want to move them manually, why don't you say so?

Comment: Sorry, I am clarifying. When saying move manually I mean move them with hand one by one. But I want to change in attribute table with copy/paste all cells, this is easier.

Comment: So you need to work with CSV.

Comment: If there is a way working with the attribute table, I will edit. If no, yes I need to work with CSV.

Comment: The attribute table is - as the name says - only attributes, not the basic spatial information.

Comment: Where the spatial information is exist?

Comment: It is accessible via the CSV, for example.

Comment: In my previous question, there is a shapefile folder. When I open it, save as a CSV and open the CSV, I can not see spatial information.

Comment: How about you provide some example data?

Comment: Yes sure, a sample data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cs35nhwze77y86n/_PluginsTestShapeFile.rar?dl=0

Comment: Meh, I got fixed on the CSV issue and forgot you haven't got a CSV to start with. Use `add geometry column/values` on your shapefile, then export it as CSV.

Comment: **What is the 'logic' in your points 'move'** ? Will all points be treated the same way ? is it for example a simple translation ? Are the moves randomly chosen ... if you don't want to move points manually you got to have a clear logic ... if all points are treated differently you certainly have a file with the 'destination' of all points you want to move ... please clarify ...

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to specify the coordinates of the point and have it move to specified coordinates if so the attributes table is not how you do it, instead use the Vertex tool - right click on the point and window should pop up where you can edit the coordinates.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for detailed answer. I have approximately 500 points per shapefile. One by one, it is very difficult. So, I thought that If I open the attribute table and change the columns of latitude/longitude with my ordered lat/lon list, the problem will be solved. Is there any alternative way to change multiple points in eash way?

Comment: I can only think of exporting the attribute table with lan/lon into excel, editing them there and bring the csv back to qgis and set the edited values as lat/lon. This should work regardless of how many columns you have.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Before asking this question, my goal was what you said. I could not succeed and I asked this question:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317225/editing-and-saving-csv-file-to-use-in-plugin-for-qgis 
I will be glad if you look at my question.